# Cannot connect to Node.js server using socket.io + express + webpack, requests return 404 errors

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to test my first socket.io server/client codes. But it failed.

My HTML file is like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to socket project</h1>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.8.js"></script>
  <script src="./dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My client side code is like this:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9999');
console.log('Connected: ', socket.connected);
socket.emit('setPlayerPosition', {
  reason: 'It\'s my birthday'
});
```

My server code is like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('./webpack.base');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = 9999;
const devPort = port - 1;
const domain = 'http://127.0.0.1:' + devPort;

const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(webpack({
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    main: [
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      `webpack-dev-server/client?${domain}`,
      config.entry.main
    ]
  },
  output: config.output,
  plugins: config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]),
  module: config.module,
  resolve: config.resolve,
}), {
  publicPath: `${domain}/`,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  port: devPort,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
  }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('setPlayerPosition', function(id, msg) {
        console.log('Position' + msg.reason);
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('serverMsg', {
      msg: 'hello'
    });
    });
});

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/media'));
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end(
        fs.readFileSync('./public/index.html')
          .toString()
          .replace(/\.\/dist\//g, `${domain}/`)
      );
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on port', port);
});

devServer.listen(devPort);
```

I can connect with `http` but when I use `socket.io` it gives me a 404 error.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, the client side console log is "Connected: false".

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: 404 for which resource?

Comment: @robertklep just normal request. `http://localhost:9999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an HTTP server to host the `socket.io` server:

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

However, you're not calling `.listen()` on that server instance, so it won't be listening on port 9999 as you might expect.

Here's an alternative setup that should work:

```
const port   = 9999;
const app    = express();
const server = app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server is running on port', port);
});
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: Thanks now I see the problem. But why does the console log still show "Connected: false"?

Comment: @newguy because connecting takes some time. You should wait for the `connect` (and/or `connect_error) event.